# Can't display image PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

My problem is, when I upload a picture to a database, the upload is successful but the picture isn’t displayed. This is my code:

SQL file:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `images` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,`name` varchar(100) default NULL,`size` int(11) default NULL,`type` varchar(20) default NULL,`content` mediumblob,PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

`Index.php`

```php
<?php if (!empty($uploadOk)): ?>
        <div>
            <h3>Image Uploaded:</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="image.php?id=<?=$imageId ?>" width="150px">
            <strong>Embed</strong>: <input size="25" value='<img src="image.php?id=<?=$imageId ?>">'><br>
        </div>

        <hr>
    <? endif; ?>

    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <div>
        <h3>Image Upload:</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Image</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500000">
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload"><br>
      </div>
    </form>

                    </tr>';}mysql_close();?>
```

`image.php`

```php
<?php

// verify request id.
if (empty($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    echo 'A valid image file id is required to display the image file.';
    exit;
}

$imageId = $_GET['id'];

//connect to mysql database
if ($conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'db_name')) {
    $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $content);
    $sql = "SELECT type, content FROM images where id = {$imageId}";

    if ($rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        $imageData = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        mysqli_free_result($rs);
    } else {
        echo "Error: Could not get data from mysql database. Please try again.";
    }
    //close mysqli connection
    mysqli_close($conn);

} else {
    echo "Error: Could not connect to mysql database. Please try again.";
}   

if (!empty($imageData)) {
    // show the image.
    header("Content-type: {$imageData['type']}");
    echo $imageData['content'];
} ?>
```

`getImage.php`

```php
<?php 
$id = $_GET['id'];
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "pass");
mysql_select_db("db_name");


$sql = "SELECT content FROM images WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query("$sql");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_close($link);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['content'];
?>
```

This code worked. I think the SQL database is incorrect or has problems to display images.

Comment: Where did the above source code etc come from?  Because the code doesn't work and for me to help, need to know what needs to be in the mysql table so I can build it on my machine.

Comment: Comment out the `header()` and try to access image.php?id=... directly. See if there's an error or anything. Also, you're using mysqli_real_escape_string, but not using it on imageId. I hate that function, so I never ever use it, and don't know how it reacts when you pass in an undefined variable.

Comment: I don't know where code is from, in mysql table must to be image and description of image, like article or blog news...

Comment: The second file does not open a picture that is not displayed is

Comment: So i need developer with experience to tell me if i mistake in sql file because i think it is sql file error, because this code is working for me and i move on another hosting not save sql file and now i have that problem

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your SQL file. There is a lot wrong with your index.php file. The reason your not seeing pictures is because your not uploading them. There are no pictures in the db to see.

Comment: Your image.php file and your getImage.php file do the same thing so not sure why you have both when index.php only uses image.php.

Comment: I know that,  getImage.php file used for other proccess...

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the image, you should use AJAX from JavaScript.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `images` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,`name` varchar(100) default NULL,`size` int(11) default NULL,`type` varchar(20) default NULL,`content` mediumblob,PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM;

Because everything on this code work properly but problem is in mysql database (table)